# Как сделать 2 бесконечно, по очереди бегущие строки

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Есть массив строк и они должны по очереди выежать и заезжать за контейнер

Первый выезжает сверху слева и заезжает за контейнер, двигаясь направо, потом второй снизу справа выезжает и заезжает за контейнер, двигаясь налево и так по кругу, но по очереди

На данный момент, имеется только вёрстка этого макета как на видео, но скидывать наверное не нужно. Можете пожалуйста показать примером или же если есть готовое решение, буду сильно благодарен

Comment: Не стоит материться на видео

Comment: это не мое видео :Д

Comment: помогите пж сделать такую анимацию (

Comment: Текст бегущий слева направо? Сомнительная идея...

Comment: А что не так? Просто задание такое

Comment: Не важно ваше видео или нет, не стоит выкладывать видео с матом тут в принципе

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

1. Запоминаем наши `div`-ы в переменные и на их основе создаём [словарик](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Это нам понадобится чтобы легко и просто переключаться между правым и левым `div`-ом
2. С помощью [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) достаём значение переменной `--animation-duration`, который объявлен в CSS
3. Достаем оттуда число и делим пополам. На пополам надо делить, чтобы скрипт успевал обновлять значения для каждой из сторон. Иначе он будет либо слишком быстро менять либо слишком медленно, а нам надо чтобы прямо перед началом очередной стороны текст менялся
4. Т.к. нам надо циклически гулять по массиву, то я использую формулу `(currIndex + 1) % arrayLength`. Именно `% arrayLength` позволяет гулять циклически по массиву, т.к. он возвращает значения от 0 до `arrayLength - 1`. **P.S. Но эта формула верна только если вы всегда увеличиваете индекс. Если вы будете уменьшать, то в более общем виде формула будет такой: `(arrayLength + currIndex +/- 1) % arrayLength`**

```js
const texts = [
  'Right text one',
  'Left text one',
  'Right text two',
  'Left text two',
  'Right text three',
  'Left text three',
];

const rightSide = document.querySelector('.text-from-right');
const leftSide = document.querySelector('.text-from-left');

const sidesMap = new Map([
  [rightSide, leftSide], 
  [leftSide, rightSide]
]);

const animationDurationInSecs = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--animation-duration'); // '4s'
const animationDurationHalf = parseFloat(animationDurationInSecs) / 2; // 2

let currTextIndex = -1;
let currSide = leftSide;

setInterval(() => {
  currTextIndex = (currTextIndex + 1) % texts.length;
  currSide = sidesMap.get(currSide);
  
  currSide.innerHTML = texts[currTextIndex];
  
}, animationDurationHalf * 1000);
```

```css
:root {
  --animation-duration: 4s;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
}

.center-block {
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left-block,
.right-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-block {
  justify-content: start;  
}

.right-block {
  justify-content: end;
}

.text-from-left,
.text-from-right {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: fit-content;
  padding-left: 100%;
}

.text-from-left {
  animation: right-stream var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
}

.text-from-right {
  animation: left-stream var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
}

@keyframes right-stream {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes left-stream {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="block left-block">
    <div class="text-from-left">Left text onee</div>
  </div>

  <div class="block center-block"></div>

  <div class="block right-block">
    <div class="text-from-right">Right text onee</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы на js у меня текст менялся? Ну смысле по очереди из массива брался

Comment: @jsususi Изменил код, добавил JS

Comment: @EzioMercer а текст справа, должен исчезать при соприкосновении с кубом? (У меня он исчезает именно тогда)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Нет, он должен исчезать когда касается конец текста справа. Не знаю почему у вас так работает, трудно ответить так. Можете поиграться с CSS и добиться того чтобы у вас текст исчезал только в конце, а потом написать в комментариях что именно вы изменили, я гляну у себя. Если и у меня это будет работать и у вас, то я дам вам знать, чтобы вы внесли эти же изменения в вопросе :)